# how to make a leaderboard based on who has the most xp?

Tags: discord.py

Right now i have a working xp/leveling system, as said in the title is there a way of showing who has the most xp? Kinda like a leaderboard type of thing, If somebody would give a example that would be great!

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('/xp'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "You currently have `{}` XP!".format(get_xp(message.author.id)))

user_add_xp(message.author.id, 2)


def user_add_xp(user_id: int, xp: int):
if os.path.isfile("users.json"):
    try:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
            users = json.load(fp)
        users[user_id]['xp'] += xp
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    except KeyError:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
            users = json.load(fp)
        users[user_id] = {}
        users[user_id]['xp'] = xp
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
else:
    users = {user_id: {}}
    users[user_id]['xp'] = xp
    with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)


def get_xp(user_id: int):
if os.path.isfile('users.json'):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
    return users[user_id]['xp']
else:
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've already got a way to grab the users via:

```
with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
    users = json.load(fp)
```

So, you can combine that with [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and this should give you a list in order top to bottom of users based on xp.

```
sorted(users, key=lambda x : users[x].get('xp', 0), reverse=True)
```

From there you're going to have to take that list and make it into something easy for people to digest. Here's one example.

```
high_score_list = sorted(users, key=lambda x : users[x].get('xp', 0), reverse=True)
message = ''
for number, user in enumerate(high_score_list):
    message += '{0}. {1} with {2}xp\n'.format(number + 1, user, users[user].get('xp', 0))
```

That should give you the message to send in order from top to bottom displaying their rank, name, and xp.